# Calling child component method for all iterations

Tags: lightning-web-components, parent-to-child, communication

I have a component that iterates over an array of objects, and for each one, renders a child component:

```
<template>
<template if:true={filters}>
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows horizontal-align="space">
        <template iterator:it={filters}>
            <lightning-layout-item key={it.value.label} padding="around-medium" size="4">
                <c-lwc-filter
                    filter={it.value}>
                </c-lwc-filter>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

The component c-lwc-filter has a method called exportData:

```
@api exportData(){
    let data = {};
    if(this.isInput || this.isSelect || this.isBoolean){
        data = {'value' : this.filter.value}
    }else if(this.isComposable){
        data = {'filters' : this.filter.filters};
    }else if(this.isSelectable){
        data = {'selectedOption' : this.filter.selectedOption, 'filters' : this.filter.filters};
    }else if(this.isMultiSelect){
        data = {'selected' : this.filter.selected};
    }
    return data;
}
```

I want to make a method in the parent component (which is actually a intermediate component, there is another parent) that calls the lwc filter exportData method, for all of the iterations. I mean, all of the filters that are being rendered, in the iterator. How do I accomplish that?

EDIT: Does doing this.template.querySelectorAll('c-lwc-filter') do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.template.querySelectorAll('c-lwc-filter')` will *almost* get you there. `querySeletorAll` returns a NodeList, which despite its name, is not actually an iterable list. Converting it to a list is easy:

```
let filters = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('c-lwc-filter')]
  .map(filter => filter.exportData());
```

Comment: Ok, so in that code you are already filling the filters array with the objects the exportData methods returns?

Comment: @joacoiudica Correct. The map function takes a list of inputs and does some action to produce a list of outputs.

Comment: thanks a lot man! thats exactly what I needed.